# Angular 2 - Can't pass value to model - Javascript, Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a KnowledgeElement model like this:

```
export interface KnowledgeElement {
  public knowledgE_USER_ID: number;
  public knowledgE_NAME: string;
  public knowledgE_DESCRIPTION: string;
  public knowledgE_USER_SCORE: number;
}
```

And a component like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'survey',
  moduleId: module.id,
  styleUrls: ['survey.component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'survey.component.html',
  providers: [KnowledgeElementDataService]
})

export class SurveyComponent implements OnInit {
  public knowledgeElement: KnowledgeElement = {};

  constructor(private _knowledgeList: KnowledgeElementDataService){

  }

  submitSurvey(): void {
    this.knowledgeElement.knowledgE_USER_ID = 1;
    this.knowledgeElement.knowledgE_NAME = 'Empty';
    this.knowledgeElement.knowledgE_DESCRIPTION = 'Empty';
    this.knowledgeElement.knowledgE_USER_SCORE = 1;

    this._knowledgeList.updateKnowledge(knowledgeElement);
  }
}
```

When I try to assign properties to the variable its stating:
"caused by: Cannot set property 'knowledgE_USER_ID' of undefined"

How can I assign properties to that variable so I can pass it over with the method to the service?

Comment: Is the error coming from the `submitSurvey()` method? Do you call it after submiting a form or something?

Comment: @echonax yes, the a submit button binded to it.

Comment: Can you also add the html to your question?

Comment: @echonax No reason to post it, the html contains only the button and the button works perfectly fine.

Comment: You might be messing up the directives but anyway.. What does `console.log(this)` is giving you inside the `submitSurvey()`?

Comment: @echonax its giving me the object itself (methods), also the variable knowledgeElement has properties assigned to it suprisingly but still error is thrown.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the error inside submitSurvey?

Comment: @echonax Yes: knowledgeElement is not defined
    at SurveyComponent.submitSurvey, it fails on line this._knowledgeList.updateKnowledge(knowledgeElement);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this._knowledgeList.updateKnowledge(knowledgeElement);
```

should be

```
this._knowledgeList.updateKnowledge(this.knowledgeElement);
```

you have a "typo", you should be passing `this.knowledgeElement` not `knowledgeElement` like a local variable :-)

Comment: Thanks, seems it was something that incredibly stupid. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You try it please

```
export class SurveyComponent implements OnInit {
   knowledgeElement: KnowledgeElement;
   submitSurvey(): void {
        this.knowledgeElement = {knowledgE_USER_ID: 1,
        knowledgE_NAME: "string",
        knowledgE_DESCRIPTION: "string",
        knowledgE_USER_SCORE: 2};
   }
...
```

And remove public modifier in interface.

Check whether null or not. like this. After print

```
<div *ngIf="knowledgeElement">{{knowledgeElement.knowledgE_USER_ID}}</div>
```

Comment: @PiotrJerzyMamenas update my answer. I tried your code. It works well.

Answer (score 0):

currently your instance member is

```
 public knowledgeElement: KnowledgeElement = {};
```

change it to

```
 public knowledgeElement = new KnowledgeElement();
```

and also change interface to class

yours 
export interface KnowledgeElement {

change it to
export class KnowledgeElement {

Comment: `KnowledgeElement` is an interface not a class. And even if it was a class what difference would it make?

Comment: actually it will stop the issue for undefine I also had this issue in mine project.

Comment: So you think an empty `object` (`{}`) is equal to `undefined`?

Comment: I m also new to TypeScript, but as it is inherently Javascript this should not be the case. But when I did initialize variable by new then I got rid of that.

Comment: @PiotrJerzyMamenas you need to initialize it before use in html template. I've same issue with class type and it did solve by initializing it with new operator